# UIModalPresentationFormSheet is not working for UIImagePickerController(For Camera) in iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios7

I'm working with an app which needs to support on both iOS6 and iOS7
The `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` (`modalPresentationStyle`) is not working for `UIImagePickerController`(For Camera) in iOS7 but it's working fine in iOS6.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you get any kind of error messages or compiler errors when you make this change?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's documentation of `UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), it should be displayed inside a popover. If you cannot accommodate this, you may have to roll your own, or use open source.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code for getting image from Camera or Gallery in ipad and iphone. As in ipad, you are not able to do presentmodalviewcontroller for getting image.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.selectedImageView.bounds inView:self.selectedImageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    self.popOver = popover;
} else {
     [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```